# query WHERE combination of lookup fields in a set

Tags: apex, soql

I have two junction objects, say A and B, between User and Account. Now my scenario is that, when a record of A between User U1 and Account A1 - is deleted -> then I need to clear the user field having value U1 in object B records under the same account A1.

So in the bulkified implementation of this logic in a trigger, I have to consider the whole trigger.old( 200 records) and hence do the query in such a way

```
SELECT .. FROM B__c WHERE Account__c in Set1 AND User__c in Set2
```

Now this could possibly bring many unwanted records i.e. B records under A1 but under a different user say U2 that was a parent in another deleted A record. So my question is how to make this query more selective, such that I only want matching pairs of AccountID and UserID i.e. I only want B records in A1+U1 , A2+U2 etc occur. Hope I was clear.

An idea that came to my mind( haven't done feasibility check), create a formula field on object B, that contains the concatenated vlues of AccountID + UserID of that B record. Then use the WHERE clause as

```
SELECT ... FROM B__c WHERE IDConCat_Field__c IN SetWith IDConcatValues
```

I was hoping to actually implement this solution completely using apex and SOQL, Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concatenation scheme is certainly a viable solution. Your implementation will be much simpler if you use `CASESAFEID`, because a formula uses 15 digit values, but `Apex` uses 18.

Your formula would then look like:

```
CASESAFEID(Account__c) & CASESAFEID(User__c)
```

Then, in `Apex`, you could write helpers along the lines of:

```
public static Set<String> getConcatenatedLookup(List<A__c> records)
{
    Set<String> values = new Set<String>();
    for (A__c record : records) values.add(getConcatenatedLookup(record));
    return values;
}
public static String getConcatenatedLookup(A__c record)
{ // if neither reference is nillable this method is of little help
    String a = (record.Account__c == null) ? '' : record.Account__c;
    String u = (record.User__c == null) ? '' : record.User__c;
    return a + u;
}
```

Then getting the corresponding records is easy:

```
public static List<B__c> findCorrespondingJunctions(List<A__c> records)
{
    return [SELECT Id FROM B__c WHERE Concat__c IN :getConcatenatedLookup(records)];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have implemented the same. Works great ( as of now ;) ) . Lets see what bugs the future holds for us. Cheers.

Comment: @Stygon Good luck!